# POST large JSON using OkHttpClient for Android

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I have a method that posts json to my server, The method is as below

```
sync_urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(context.getResources().getString(R.string.transprocessorURL));
                    sync_urlBuilder.append("?str=" + URLEncoder.encode(json.toString(), "UTF-8").toString());
                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, String.valueOf(json));
                    Request okHttprequest = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(sync_urlBuilder.toString())
                            .post(body)
                            .build();
                    okHttpClient.newCall(okHttprequest).enqueue(this);
```

This works fine, however when the length of the json body is quite large the URL  exceeds the 8190 apache limit for URL length. My question is how can I post such large URL lengths without running into HTTP error 414.

Comment: do not use GET but POST and post json as body ... but of course it depends on what does server-side expect to get ... If it doesn't expect POST method at all then an answer is: you cannot fix it, without changing the serverside

Comment: Chill with the downvotes, can you not see am using post and not get and the json is the the body from the requestbody..???

Comment: As for the server side its using REQUEST which allows both get and post. But as I have shared and clearly visible am using post with json as the body

Comment: Then why you appending json to the url, too?

Comment: appending the ?str= to the json. should I have it soley as RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json); and then in the URL append the ?str= to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it by adjusting my code to shown below

```
                    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("str", String.valueOf(json))
                        .build();
                    Request okHttprequest = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(context.getResources().getString(R.string.transprocessorURL))
                            .post(formBody)
                            .build();
                    okHttpClient.newCall(okHttprequest).enqueue(this);
```